# Proving: $\partial_v f(a)$ exists if and only if so does $\partial_v f_k(a)$ $(\forall k)$ (in Normed Vector Spaces).

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I'm rereading some sections of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* and attempting to generalize some results (usually to Normed Vector Spaces). I'm struggling to prove the (generelized version of) the theorem below, so I thought of asking for a hand. Throughout the post let $V$ and $W$ be NVSs, with $V'\subseteq V$ open and $f$ a function $V'\to W$.

**Definition:** given $a\in V'$ and a vector $v\in V$, we define (assuming the limit exists)
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) := \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t},$$

and, in the case $v=e_i$ for a basis vector $e_i$,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) := \frac{\partial f}{\partial e_i}(a).$$

---

**Theorem:** let $\dim W = m$ so that $f(v)=(f_1(v), \ldots ,f_m(v))$. Then $\partial_v f(a)$ exists if and only if so does $\partial_v f_k(a)$ $(\forall k)$, in which case
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) = \sum_{k=1}^me_k\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial v}(a).$$

*Proof:*
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) & = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+hv)-f(a)}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^me_k\frac{f_k(a+hv)-f_k(a)}{h}\right)\\
& \stackrel{*}{=} \sum_{k=1}^me_k\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_k(a+hv)-f_k(a)}{h}\right)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^me_k\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial v}(a).\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

---

In my attempt to justify the equality $\stackrel{*}{=}$, I've come up with -what I believe is- a lemma which if true would legitimize the equality. However, now I find myself struggling to prove said lemma.

**Is the lemma below true? If so, how could one prove it? If not, how else could one justify the equality $\stackrel{*}{=}$?**

**Lemma (?):** Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space with $p$ a limit point of $X'\subseteq X$. Let $W$ be a topological vector space with $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ as a basis of $W$, and let $f:X'\to W$ be a function. Then
$$\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x\to p} f_\alpha(x) = L_\alpha \ (\forall \alpha\in A)$$

where by $f_\alpha$ (or $L_\alpha$) I mean the $\alpha$ component of $f$ (or $L$).

Answer (score 3):

Your lemma is not true for an arbitrary topological vector space.  In an arbitrary topological vector space $W$ with basis $(e_\alpha)$, the function $p_\alpha:W\to\mathbb{R}$ taking a vector to its $\alpha$th component need not be continuous (so the forward direction of your statement will fail).  Indeed, any nonzero linear functional $W\to\mathbb{R}$ can be realized as $p_\alpha$ with respect to some basis, and a linear functional does not have to be continuous.

It is true for finite-dimensional topological vector spaces.  In this case, you can just use the fact that any finite-dimensional topological vector space is isomorphic (as a topological vector space) to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the product topology for some $n$.  Then your statement just amounts to the fact that the change-of-basis map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ between the standard basis and the chosen basis $(e_\alpha)$ is a homeomorphism (which is true since any linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, so both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous).